# How to get a C++17 environment on macOS High Sierra?

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, llvm, c++17

[`macOS` `High Sierra`](https://www.apple.com/macos/high-sierra/) and [`Xcode 9`](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) come with an old version of `LLVM`. It's not obvious which version of `LLVM` it is because of version number mangling. However, it's apparent it's old as the latest version of `LLVM` supports `C++17` but features like `std::optional` are not available.

I'd like to write some `C++17` code using a Mac. What `toolchains` are available and what has the fewest complications to get working? My thoughts so far:

- `LLVM` via `Homebrew` -- interference with/by `Xcode`?
- `GCC` via `Homebrew`
- Above compiled from source

Any preferred method?

Answer (score 1):

This 'answer' is not an answer to your question.  These are the handy bookmarks I use.

I'd use Homebrew to install clang++ (see link below).  But if you really want Xcode to interop with it, I'd suggest the "bad news" of wait for Apple, or try out their latest beta.  And keep in mind that Apple's "Objective-C++" (*.mm) probably requires Apple's secret sauce, if you have some sort of C++ / Cocoa project.

C++17 implementation status:

- https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

Xcode -to- CLang version:

- https://gist.github.com/yamaya/2924292

Homebrew to get CLang (clang++):

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227026/how-to-install-recent-clang-with-homebrew

Comment: I posted the above as an "answer" because it was too much to post in a comment.

Comment: I don't need Xcode interop, I just need a working C++17 toolchain that I can use on the Mac, from the command line. Thoughts?

Comment: Homebrew... I've had good luck with that route, which is what I use for my C++17 coding.